# How do shift certain rows over based on column values?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
A  B  C  D
X  5  6  5
Y  3  1  2
X  9  7  5
   3  5  2
9  8  7  NaN
5  2  2  NaN
X  4  3  1
Y  3  2  1
6  8  0  NaN
```

Notice in Column A there are certain values that are letters (i.e. X,Y). In Column A there are also values that should be in Column B (i.e. the numbers). How do I specify in Pandas to say:

- For every value that is not X, Y, or Empty, shift the specific row over by 1 column.

My desired output being:

```
A  B  C  D
X  5  6  5
Y  3  1  2
X  9  7  5
   3  5  2
   9  8  7 
   5  2  2 
X  4  3  1
Y  3  2  1
   6  8  0
```

Even something like this would work for me:

```
A  B  C  D  E
X  5  6  5  
Y  3  1  2 
X  9  7  5  
   3  5  2  NaN
   9  8  7  NaN
   5  2  2  NaN
X  4  3  1  
Y  3  2  1  
   6  8  0  NaN
```

There should be some sort of function to say, for every value that is X, Y or Empty, ignore and the ones that are numbers shift over... or vice versa.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

**Basically: how do I say; anything that is not these specific values, take that row and shift everything over?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be to convert the DataFrame into a list of lists and then insert an empty element into each row that doesn't have X, Y, or ''.

```
df = df.values.tolist()
for row in df:
    if row[0] not in ['X', 'Y', '']:
        row.insert(0, '')
result = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=list('ABCDE')
```

**Output:**

```
   A  B  C    D   E
0  X  5  6  5.0 NaN
1  Y  3  1  2.0 NaN
2  X  9  7  5.0 NaN
3     3  5  2.0 NaN
4     9  8  7.0 NaN
5     5  2  2.0 NaN
6  X  4  3  1.0 NaN
7  Y  3  2  1.0 NaN
8     6  8  0.0 NaN
```

Comment: So this actually worked.. the only problem is, I believe it also shifted for the empty rows `''`. How do you think I can define those?

Comment: Is there anyway I can fill the empty rows with something before performing this operation? What would be the command to "fill empty cells in this column with X".

Comment: You can do df['A'] = df['A'].fillna('X') or df['A'] = df['A'].str.replace('', 'X')

Comment: Hell yes. "Don't worry, by hacky." Thank you, sir. I got it working.

Comment: Quick question, instead of writing "ABCDE", how would I make it more custom values?

Comment: Glad you got it working. You can just specify the column names by putting them into a list. i.e. columns = ["...", "...", "...", etc.]

Comment: Got it, appreciate it a lot Riley.

Comment: Any chance you can help me out with this one. I'm thinking it's going to be another for loop again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44576386/how-to-add-attribute-tag-column-to-dataframe

Comment: Just responded to your question