# How to add attribute/tag column to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

```
security   ticker   $amount
Apple      AAPL     5000
Coors      TAP      2000
Microsoft  MSFT     3000
US Dollar           10000
Alumina    AWC.AU   1000
Telstra    TLS.AU   1000
AU Dollar           2000
```

And so on...

How can I make it so that:

- For every blank row in "ticker", (whichever is easier) but preferably add the attribute US Dollar to all the securities listed above it but before the next one if that makes sense... so in essence, I'd like it to add US Dollar to Apple, Coors, Microsoft; and add AU Dollar to Alumina, Telstra, etc.. We can list this in an extra column.
- If it is easier, I can settle on exporting US Dollar, AU dollar and then $ amount, into a different dataframe.
- Once I do this, I'd like to delete "US Dollar","AU dollar" and their respective rows out of the dataframe.

Ideally, if I can add the attribute that would be tremendous. That way I can search for total $amount United States securities with a simple query.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution, but maybe give this a try?

First I recreated your DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'security': ['Apple', 'Coors', 'Microsoft', 'US Dollar', 'Alumina', 'Telstra', 'AU Dollar'],
                   'ticker': ['AAPL', 'TAP', 'MSFT', "", 'AWC.AU', 'TLS.AU', ""],
                   '$amount': [5000, 2000, 3000, 10000, 1000, 1000, 2000]})
```

Then I used `np.where` to extract AU Dollar and US Dollar from the security column

```
df['Extra Column'] = np.where(df['ticker'] == "", df['security'], np.nan)
df['Extra Column'] = df['Extra Column'].fillna(method='bfill')
df['Extra Amount'] = np.where(df['ticker'] == "", df['$amount'], np.nan)
df['Extra Amount'] = df['Extra Amount'].fillna(method='bfill')
result = df[df['ticker']!='']
```

**Output:**

```
   $amount   security  ticker Extra Column  Extra Amount
0     5000      Apple    AAPL    US Dollar       10000.0
1     2000      Coors     TAP    US Dollar       10000.0
2     3000  Microsoft    MSFT    US Dollar       10000.0
4     1000    Alumina  AWC.AU    AU Dollar        2000.0
5     1000    Telstra  TLS.AU    AU Dollar        2000.0
```

Comment: So, is this only working for Strings that contain the word "dollar" in it? What if I were to say, have Japanese Yen.

Comment: hmmm.. that just seems to only create the new columns.. I was not able to get the attribute in Extra Column. The original way works, but how can we bend it to specify basically, any currency.

Comment: Worked for me. How are you constructing your dataframe? Make sure the string representation for blank values "" is consistent with np.nan

Comment: Got it, so basically I just added an "X" first where there were blank cells and then modified your code to basically say `np.where(df['ticker'] == "X"`. I think there is some sort of weird issue where it can't read the blank cell (something I've run in before). Anyways, you are the best. I really cannot thank you enough.

Comment: My pleasure! It's a lot of fun trying to solve these problems.

Comment: Last last last question haha - For some reason, the last currency is not being attributed.. how do you think this is happening? // EDIT: nevermind. that's my fault.

Comment: The last currency? Do you mean 'AU Dollar'? Can you give an example?

Comment: Totally my fault - I had an error in my code. Thank you again. Really appreciate it.